# How to print data comming from api in small chunks in loop

Tags: node.js, json, api, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I am making a telegram bot where i am receving data from api call. the api is returning me data like this [image]

articles is the array and i want to retrive all the news from this .

when i do it without loop it work fine with no error[image]

But when i am trying to print all data from array in look see below image[image]
it gives me error like this (see in image)[image]

How to print this data?

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `for` instead of `.forEach`

Answer (score 0):

By the logic, i will tell "i" go to far away, but to be sure to not have any error, juste check if `newData.articles[i].source.name` is defined in a "if", if it's true, you assigned to your variables and send the message, if not, just go next

Answer (score 0):

First Check the `newData.articles[i].source` is defined

Change Your `for` loop Like this

```
    for(let i =0;i<itr;i++){
      if(newData.articles[i]&&newData.articles[i].source){
        let name=newData.articles[i].source.name||"Noname",
        title=newData.articles[i].source.title||"No Title",
        description=newData.articles[i].description||"No Description";
        bot.sendMessage(chatId,`${name}\n\nTitle : ${title}\n\nDescription : ${description}`)
      }       
    }
```